# Add pk for a ForeignKey Field after the submit of a form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Iam trying to change/add the pk for a ForeignKey Field after I submitted data via form.
The form doesn't ask for the ForeignKey, this should be done via the Slug:

```
Model.py

class Verantwortlicher(models.Model):

masznahme = models.ForeignKey(Masznahmen, verbose_name='Maßnahme')
verantwortlicher = models.CharField('Verantwortlicher Mitarbeiter',
                                    max_length=30)
faelligkeit = models.DateField('Fälligkeit')

def __str__(self):
    return self.verantwortlicher

forms.py

class VerantwortlicherForm(forms.ModelForm):

masznahme = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Masznahmen.objects.all() ,
                                   label='Maßnahme',
                                   required=False,
                                   )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(VerantwortlicherForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_id = 'id-Verantwortlicher'
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-4'
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    #self.helper.form_action = 'verantwortlicher'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
                                Fieldset(
                                        '',
                                        'verantwortlicher',
                                        'faelligkeit',
                                        ),
                                FormActions(
                                            Submit('submit', 'Datensatz hinzufügen', css_class="button white")
                                           )
                                )
class Meta:
    model = Verantwortlicher

View.py

def verantwortlicher(request, slug):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VerantwortlicherForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            masznahme = Masznahmen.objects.get(slug=slug)
            form.masznahme = masznahme.pk
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('aktionsplan')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = VerantwortlicherForm()

    return render_to_response('verbrauchererfassung/verantwortlicher.html',
                              {'form': form},
                              context,
                              )
```

In Return I get a valueError:

Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:

Cannot assign None: "Verantwortlicher.masznahme" does not allow null values.

Where is the error in my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess You should do it like this:

```
vwortlicher = form.save(commit=False)
masznahme = Masznahmen.objects.get(slug=slug)
vwortlicher.masznahme = masznahme.pk
vwortlicher.save()
```

### After discussion on chat:

From full stacktrace we figured that actual error reside in `if form.is_valid()` line.
Culprit happened to be missing `exclude` in Meta of form class in forms.py.
Form validation expected input from `masznahme` field widget which wasn't there

Comment: Sorry for this late reply - I still get the same ValueError. The debug info has still 'none' as input for masznahme

Comment: Well then, are You sure that appropriate `masznahme` object actually exists ?  Cause this exception basically says that You are trying to assing null value to masznahme field of Verantwortlicher model which is forbidden. Also where exactly this exception is thrown ? Could you past trace ?

Comment: Iam pretty sure I use <a href="{% url 'verantwortlicher' m.slug %}"> to refere to the site where m is m from masznahmen

Comment: then install it: `sudo pip install ipdb` (assuming you are on linux) and then paste something like this: `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` belowe line in which you check form validation (in views) then run dev server (or restart it - just in case) and when your code execution will reach this line in your views file it will stop and promp you for instructions. You will be then able to debug code line by line - in prompt you can use basic python syntax (AFAIK, i really mainly using prints and comparisions) for instance printing value of variable.

Comment: Then you could go to next line by typing `next` (or `n`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63165/discussion-between-maximilian-kindshofer-and-4rlekin).